# How to properly add an event lister to an input when using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I want to add an event lister to an input, so that when a user is focused on the input and presses `Enter`, a function of my choice is ran.

I know how to do this with regular javascript but could not find reference to the proper setup in the React documentation.

JS:

```
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");

input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.handleEnterPress
  }
})
```

React Mockup:

```
class Example extends React.Component {

handleEnterPress = () => {
// some more code here
}

render () {
return(
<input id='myInput'/>
)
}

export default Example
```

Comment: In your React component, you are missing a closing `)` in the return statement in the `render()` function.

Comment: @g-dg Ok.. I'll correct that but it was meant to demonstrate the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `onKeyUp`:

```
class Example extends React.Component {

handleKeyPress = e => {
  if (e.which === 13) {  // <-- Enter
     // enter code here
  }
}

render () { 
   return ( <input type="text" id='myInput' onKeyUp={handleKeyPress}/> )
}

export default Example
```

Some notes about the key events just in case you would care about other than `Enter` in the future:

> **KeyPress** ignores delete, arrows, home/end, ctrl, alt, shift etc while
>   **KeyDown** and **KeyUp** don't

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
handleKeyPress = (event) => {
   if(event.key == 'Enter'){
   console.log('enter press here! ')
  }
 }

 class SomeComponent  extends Component {
 render () {
   return(
     <div>
       <input type="text"  onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
    </div>
  }
```